# Uploading Multiple Images to Firebase at Once

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload multiple images to my firebase database at once. I will be needing HTML as well.
Here is what I have found by research, but I think due to not having correct HTML (maybe) it doesn't work.

```js
fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
    //Get files
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        var imageFile = e.target.files[i];

        uploadImageAsPromise(imageFile);
    }
});

//Handle waiting to upload each file using promise
function uploadImageAsPromise (imageFile) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(fullDirectory+"/"+imageFile.name);

        //Upload file
        var task = storageRef.put(imageFile);

        //Update progress bar
        task.on('state_changed',
            function progress(snapshot){
                var percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
                uploader.value = percentage;
            },
            function error(err){

            },
            function complete(){
                var downloadURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;
            }
        );
    });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="fileButton">Upload</button>

<input id="imageFile" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

Comment: which framework are you using??

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add `console.log` statements into your code and check if functions are being called. That helps a little.

Alright, so what I did here I was following this [link](https://medium.com/typecode/a-strategy-for-handling-multiple-file-uploads-using-javascript-eb00a77e15f). Basically, you listen to changes on your image input and push these files into an array. Then, when you submit the form, you have the array ready to be sent to firebase.

The snippet below is working fine :)

```js
const fileCatcher = document.getElementById("fileCatcher");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
let fileList = [];
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 

    console.log('Input has changed');
    fileList = []; //Reset the list
    const files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileList.push(files[i]);
    }
});

fileCatcher.addEventListener('submit', function(e){ 

    e.preventDefault(); //Block the form from reloading the page
    console.log(fileList);
    const files = fileInput.files.list;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        var imageFile = fileList[i];
        //uploadImageAsPromise(imageFile);
    }
});
```

```html
<form id = "fileCatcher"> 
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this code seems to be giving me 2 errors -  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' & 'failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Well, you need to make sure the ids of the elements in the html are exactly the same as those being called by `document.getElementById()`. That's probably why the first error is happening. About the second error, when does it happen?

Comment: What all should I have taken from my original code? Right now I just tried applying your snippet without anything from my old code.

Comment: The code seems to be working now. I do get multiple images uploaded to the database. However, I seem to have this error - Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: uploader is not defined
    at progress (tryhard.php:62)
    at Me.t.next (task.ts:84)
    at async.ts:27